# The usage of the verb AGREE with the indicative and subjunctives moods

Tags: subjunctives

Is my thinking correct or not? I think “agree” can convey different moods such as the indicative and the subjunctive.

> **The indicative (facts)** 1 I agree that the demise of London zoo would be terrible 2 I agree that he is the ablest of us.
>
> **the subjunctive**  3 They agreed that the meeting should be postponed. 4 They agreed that the meeting be postponed.

These are hard to classify:

> 6 I agreed that she would come. (does it mean 1) I agreed that her
> come would take place in the future. Or 2) I gave my permission for
> her to come.)
>
> 7 I agree that she will come.  (does it mean 1) I agree that her come
> will take place in the future. Or 2) I give my permission for her to
> come.)

Can you clarify 6 and 7 and let me know if 4 is correct?

Comment: (6) and (7) have the first meaning (except that it should be 'her coming'). For the sense of 'giving permission', (6) needs _could_ or _should_, (7) needs _can_ or _may_.